# EXC_BAD_ACCESS pointing to function header

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, debugging, exc-bad-access

I'm getting an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`, but XCode isn't pointing me to a line of code. Rather, it's pointing me to a function header in the `.m` file, that is:

```
-    (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker 
   didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
```

Why there, of all places? Did it manage to figure out that it should've sent the object to an object of that class, but the object was deallocated?

The top of the stack trace is:

```
#0  0x02c2a09b in objc_msgSend ()
#1  0x0032face in -[FDTakeController imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:] (self=0x1449cbd0, _cmd=0x1cc2439, picker=0x13d6b670, info=0x13de6710) at /Users/csaftoiu/iPhone Dev/Proj/libs/FDTake/FDTakeController.m:239
#2  0x018f3e3e in -[UIImagePickerController _imagePickerDidCompleteWithInfo:] ()
#3  0x14940d11 in PLNotifyImagePickerOfImageAvailability ()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't necessarily saying the error is in the method name but in that method. Are you calling any methods from within the `imagePickerController`? If so it is usually caused by that item no longer existing and has been set to nil;

Comment: ah yeah it seems I was being called from a delegate, and then freeing the object that sent me the delegate, so when it went back to do its clean-up code it no longer existed. Now it makes sense - the error was in that method because its `self` no longer existed and it was sending messages to `self`.